# Check if characters in String are in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm supposed to take in a string and return true if it is in alphabetical order. So far in my solution I am able to get true from "abc" but words like "aPple" throw a false. I am assuming this is because some of the characters are capitalized but I don't know where I am going wrong. This is what I have.

```
public bool IsAlphabetical(string s)
    {
        char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort(c);
        return (c.SequenceEqual(s));
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the other overloads of `SequenceEqual`?

Comment: Rather than sorting the entire array, you can return false as soon as you discover a pair of characters that are not in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need not case-sensitive comparison, you can try this

```
public static bool IsAlphabetical(string s,bool checkWithoutCase=true)
{
    var c = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Sort(c);
    var equal = c.SequenceEqual(s);

    // check without case
    if (!equal && checkWithoutCase)
    {
        s = s.ToLower();
        Array.Sort(c = s.ToCharArray());
        equal = c.SequenceEqual(s);
    }
    return equal;
}
```

or linq variant ( I am not sure what is faster)

```
public static bool IsAlphabetical(string s, bool checkWithoutCase=true, bool checkWithCase=true)
{
    var equal=false;
    
    if (checkWithCase) equal= s.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(s);
    
    // check without case
    if (!equal && checkWithoutCase)
    {
      s=s.ToLower();
     equal = s.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(s);
    }
    
    return equal;
}
```

Comment: Worked exactly as I needed it to Thank you. I have no idea why I didn't think to make the capital into lowercase. Just out of curiosity .. Is there a LINQ way I would be able to improve what I have ?

Comment: @YonkoH Check my answer, I added Linq

Answer (score 0):

I think that LINQ and array sorting is too much. A quick performance check proves that
https://dotnetfiddle.net/eoKP7Z

```
public static bool IsAlphabetical(string s, bool checkWithoutCase = true)
{
    var comparisonType = checkWithoutCase ?
        System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase :
        System.StringComparison.Ordinal;

    for (var idx = 1; idx < s.Length; idx++)
    {
        if (string.Compare(s, idx - 1, s, idx, 1, comparisonType) > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```